# What version of libc.so is compiled in ESXI 6

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-server, gcc

In ESXI 6.0 what is the version of the library at '/lib64/libc.so.6'. This would be most helpful if someone could run that and post the info. For example my ESXI 5.5 current has:

```
GNU C Library vmware release version 2.12.2, by Roland McGrath et al.   
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.6.3.
Compiled on a Linux 3.0.27 system on 2013-10-21.
Available extensions:
        crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
        GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
        Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
        BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
```

It would be most helpful in determining if upgrading to version 6 would prevent me from having to rewrite some opensource code that uses functions not built into that gcc library. Thanks!

Edit - Had the example posted from my target machine version, not ESXI.

Comment: You could install it and look for yourself!

Comment: I just don't have a test server to do so on. Also I though it might be helpful for other developers to have this info at their finger tips!

Comment: So install it in a VM.

Comment: That is some inception stuff right there buddy.

Comment: Why? What are you doing?

Comment: [Wouldn't be the first time...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0cGCW.png)

Comment: Considering you'll be needing a test instance, look at William Lam's ESXi virtual appliance!

Comment: Why downvote?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware ESXi 6.0.0 Update 1

> [root@esxi-host0:~] /lib64/libc.so.6
>   GNU C Library vmware release version 2.12.2, by Roland McGrath et al.
>   Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
>   There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>   Compiled by GNU CC version 4.6.3.
>   Compiled on a Linux 3.0.27 system on 2015-01-29.
>   Available extensions:
>           crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
>           GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
>           Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
>           BIND-8.2.3-T5B
>   libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
>   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.

Comment: Yeah, I was curious about that too. This is a clean install of ESXi 6 with update 1 installed.

Comment: Its the same :'( version, y no you update your compiler vmware

Comment: @Nimjox For the most part they don't expect you to run things directly on the hypervisor!

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's an open source UPS monitor, which I can run through a VM I know but I've seen occurrences where VMware doesn't reattach the USB pass through after a powercut...